# Make div fullwidth across the screen

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I like to make the heading background full width across the screen without using: Width:100vw;

So the background should be 100% fullwidth across the screen and portfolio h2 tag should stay centered 
http://ampersandmiami.com/new/portfolio/

The portfolio page uses a template called portfolio template and this is the code:

```html
<?php
/*
Template Name: Portfolio
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div id="heading1" class="fullwidth">
    <h2>Portfolio</h2>
</div>

<!-- / #welcome -->

<?php if (option::get('portfolio_tags') == 'on') { ?>
 <div class="portfolio-tags">
     <ul class="portfolio-taxonomies portfolio-taxonomies-filter-by">
         <li class="cat-item cat-item-all current-cat"><a href="#"><?php _e('All', 'wpzoom'); ?></a></li>
         <?php wp_list_categories( array( 'title_li' => '', 'hierarchical' => true,  'taxonomy' => 'skill-type', 'depth' => 1 ) ); ?>
     </ul>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="portfolio">

 <section id="main" class="portfolio-main" role="main">

     <ul class="portfolio-grid clearfix">

         <?php
         global $wp_query;
         global $paged;

         wp_reset_query();
         $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

         $args = array(
             'post_type' => 'portfolio',
             'paged' => $paged,
             'posts_per_page' => 99,
             );

         $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

         while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
             ?>

            <?php get_template_part('loop-portfolio'); ?>

         <?php endwhile;  ?>

     </ul>

     <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

 </section><!-- /#main -->


</div><!-- / #portfolio -->

<div class="clear"></div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

How can i make it go out the 917px width container but keep the h2 tag centered?

Comment: .fullwidth { width: 100%; text-align:center; }

Comment: Looks like you'll need to restructure the HTML; that heading is within a restricted width block (`<div id="main">` has a max-width pf 917px). Might be able to work around it with absolute positioning but it'll probably screw up the page flow.

Answer (score 0):

You could restructure your HTML slightly to make it a little easier.

**HTML**:

```
<h2 id="heading1" class="fullwidth">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
</h2>
```

**CSS**:

```
.fullwidth {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.fullwidth {
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You can try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your **DIV** before `<div id="main">`

Also You apply css as:

```
.fullwidth {display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.fullwidth h2{

    text-align: center;
    line-height: 85px;   //for centered vertically

}
```

**line-height** should be same as height of the **fullwidth**

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your *#main* div has its width restricted to 917px, so:

```
<div id="main">

    <div id="heading1" class="fullwidth">
        <h2>Portfolio</h2>
    </div>
```

^ That means that your *#heading1* div, even at 100%, won't exceed the width of *#main*.

You can resolve this by moving *#heading1* outside of *#main* and tweaking the CSS:

**HTML**

```
<div id="heading1" class="fullwidth">
    <h2>Portfolio</h2>
</div>

<div id="main">
```

**CSS**

I've added relative positioning and a *z-index* to *div#header* otherwise the bottom of the '&' image in the header falls behind *#heading1*

```
div#header {
    display: block;
    position: relative; /* '&' image fix here ... */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 21%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    z-index: 200; /* ... and here */
}

#heading1 {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 85px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: url('http://ampersandmiami.com/wp-content/themes/vimes-amp-child/images/pattern-feature.gif') repeat 0 0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #3d7576;
}

#heading1 > h2 {
    display: block;
    max-width: 917px; /* this makes the h2 the same width as #main ... */
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto; /* ... with the same margins ... */
    text-align: center; /* ... and centres the text */
}
```

This should give you something like:

[image: screengrab]

Comment: @user2019838 - what, exactly, isn't working? I just used Opera's *Inspect Element* to apply my code changes to your site and grabbed a sreenshot (attached to the answer) - is that not what you're after?

Comment: Yes not sure why but this code
 
`#heading1 {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 85px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: url('http://ampersandmiami.com/wp-content/themes/vimes-amp-child/images/pattern-feature.gif') repeat 0 0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #3d7576;
}`

does not make the background fullwidth across the screen

Comment: @user2019838 I've added in the fix I used to make the bottom of the '&' header image appear correctly - missed it out of the answer originally.

Comment: @user2019838 *"does not make the background fullwidth across the screen"* ... Ah, have you moved `<div id="heading1">` **above** `<div id="main">` ?

Comment: there is no <div id="main"> in the template . i have posted the full code of the template above .

Comment: There might not be `<div id="main">` in the template - but there **is** in the source code (I suspect it's in the end of the output from `get_header()`). Easiest way around that would be to make `#main` 100% width and then add a div inside to fix everything to 917px below *#heading1*

Answer (score 0):

you could make the heading background absolutely positioned then set left to 0 like:-

```
div#heading1 {
background: url(http://ampersandmiami.com/wp-content/themes/vimes-amp-child/images/pattern-feature.gif) repeat 0 0;
border-bottom: 3px solid #3d7576;
height: 85px;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 20%;
}
```

Then you would have to increase padding on portfoilio tags like:-

```
.portfolio-tags {
margin: 12px 0px 25px;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding-top: 24em;
}
```

Comment: The & logo should overlap the heading background, it comes to the front with position absolute.

Comment: Ok, so on your div#heading1 set z-index:0;

Comment: and on #header     position: relative;
    z-index: 1;

Comment: Your method works, just what i wanted, now the h2 tag (portfolio) should be right above "all" not centered. how can i accomplish that ? 
should also stay in the same place on mobile.

Comment: hmm, seems to me like you have this working on my screen, all you need to do is  html{overflow-x:hidden}, I may be wrong on mobile? mobile will need media queries. let me know if you need any more help

Answer (score -1):

You need to update your CSS as follows

```
div#heading1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    background: url(http://ampersandmiami.com/wp-content/themes/vimes-amp-child/images/pattern-feature.gif) repeat 0 0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #3d7576;
    height: 85px;
    left: 0;
}

.portfolio-tags {
    padding-top: 95px;
    margin: 0 0px 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

or you can move your `heading1` div outside of `main` and

```
div#heading1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: url(http://ampersandmiami.com/wp-content/themes/vimes-amp-child/images/pattern-feature.gif) repeat 0 0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #3d7576;
    height: 85px;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use vw

Comment: Use width: 100%